# Is it possible to add granular permissions on a folder without installing acl?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, files, proftpd

I have a folder `public_html` with several subfolders on Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Is it possible to add different permissions on individual subfolders for two new individual users without changing the group ownership of the folders or interfering with apache permissions? If so, how?

I would like to add two new users but restrict their write permissions to specific subfolders Each user would have access to different folders e.g. `user1` should be able to write to `public-html/folder1` and `user2` should be able to write to:

```
public_html/folder2 and 
public_html/folder3
```

If this can be done in ftp permissions separately (proftpd) that would also be an option.

ls -al in the home folder of the user which owns `public_html` gives me :

```
drwxrwxr-x 27 user1 user1 4096 Feb 12 16:54 public_html
```

all subfolders i'm interested in changing the permissions for have the permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 user1 user1  4096 Nov 22 12:52 views
```

usernames have been changed to protect the innocent. This server was not set up by myself and I have a feeling permissions are far too permissive.

Comment: ACLs are enabled by default on Ubuntu 12.04 (I forget when Linux started to have them on by default, but it's been a few years). You may need to install the `acl` package to have the shell tools, but you no longer need a mount option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the problem but what you ask can trivially be done by making these users the owner of the new directories (without changing the group).

Comment: If I change the owner won't I affect other users' access? Users with permissions on the whole public_html directory should still be able to, and already can, access folder2 and folder3. Also, the new users can't both own folder2 can they?

Comment: @codecowboy That depends on your configuration. It makes little sense to think about that without you giving us the precise configuration (access rights) for the already existing directories and the users and groups they belong to.

Comment: I've updated the question with more precise info

Comment: @codecowboy That doesn't change my answer. Unless user1 shall *not* be capable of writing to `folder2`. In that case either the group of `folder2` would have to be changed or the group rights.